# WPF control similar to ObjectListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I'm writing an application using WPF, and I need to make something that looks like this (see image):

[image: ObjectListView]

What control should I use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>If you don’t need the groupings (the “Hire as chef” and “Seek dinner invitation” headings), then</strike> [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) should get you close. You can bind its `ItemsSource` to your collection of items, and define custom columns bound to your items’ properties.

For example, you can use a [`DataGridTextColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn.aspx) for “Occupation”, [`DataGridCheckBoxColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn.aspx) for “Tells Jokes?”, and [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.aspx) for more complex properties which require a custom `DataTemplate` to visualize, such as the main “Person” column or “Cooking skill”.

**Edi**: It appears that the `DataGrid` does [support grouping](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#grouping) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should go for ListView

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754027(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754027%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)